# Transitionend on pseudo element not fired on Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fnxarqt/2/) works great in Chrome but in Edge browser the "transitionend" event does not fire.

```
function detectTransitionEvent(){
  var t;
  var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
  var transitions = {
    'transition':'transitionend',
    'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
    'MozTransition':'transitionend',
    'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
  }

  for(t in transitions){
    if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
      return transitions[t];
    }
  }
}
END_TRANSITION_EVENT = detectTransitionEvent();

function f() { alert(1); }
var d = document.getElementById("a");

d.addEventListener(END_TRANSITION_EVENT, f);
```

Please help,
Michael

Comment: Did you try adding `msTransitionEnd` to see if IE supports that *(it should support transitionend from IE10)*

Comment: @adeneo I tried that. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e1ubww3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the :before from your CSS selectors, and simply use the #a element, your fiddle will work in MS Edge. [New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ef30hdy1/)

```
#a {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
#a:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

I also found that using calc() prevents the transitionstart and transitionend events from firing in MS Edge.

```
#a{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: calc(50%);
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

From a few fiddles, I find that neither :before/:after pseudo-elements nor calc() are supported in MS Edge at the moment.  These problems are not yet mentioned at CanIUse, at W3Schools, or on the MS Edge documentation.

Incidentally, the transition MS Edge uses the first element in your object ('transition':'transitionend').